# How to fetch associated belongsToMany entities with CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have Users and Courses table with belongsToMany relation. UserTable has

```
$this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'course_id',
    'joinTable' => 'courses_users'
]);
```

and CoursesTable has

```
$this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
    'joinTable' => 'courses_users'
]);
```

Now, I want to fetch courses with user_id. In my CoursesController, I tried

```
public function myCourses()
{
    $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $courses = $this->Courses->find('all',
        ['contain' => ['Users'],
        'condition' => ['Courses.user_id' => $id]
        ]);
    $this->set('courses', $courses);
}
```

when I debug($courses) with this code, I got '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.' message. I'm searching information and trying to do it for many hours but I can't make it. How can I fetch Courses datas with user_id? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a has-and-belongs-to-many (HABTM) association with a join table of `courses_users`, you shouldn't even have a `user_id` field in your Courses table.

So now that we've determined you can't do what you were trying (`Courses.user_id`), we can look at what you thought you were trying:

```
 $courses = $this->Courses->find('all',
     ['contain' => ['Users'],
     //'condition' => ['Courses.user_id' => $id]
 ]);
```

This says "find all courses and any users that are associated with those courses".

But what you really WANT (I believe) is: "find all courses that belong to this specific user".

**To do that, you'll want to use an `matching()` instead.**

According to [the CakePHP book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data):

> A fairly common query case with associations is finding records
>   ‘matching’ specific associated data. For example if you have ‘Articles
>   belongsToMany Tags’ you will probably want to find Articles that have
>   the CakePHP tag. This is extremely simple to do with the ORM in
>   CakePHP:

```
$query = $articles->find();
$query->matching('Tags', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'CakePHP']);
});
```

So in your case, it would be something like this:

```
$query = $courses->find();
$query->matching('Users', function ($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where(['Users.id' => $id]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I asked! One thing is that I need "use ($id)" after "function ($q)"
$query->matching('Users', function ($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where(['Users.id' => $id]);
});

Comment: nice explanation !